# Docker Build fails in GCP Cloud Build - but successful in localhost

Tags: node.js, docker, npm, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-build

The following Dockerfile fails at `npm install --production` in GCP Cloud Build

```
FROM node:10.15.3-slim 

RUN sh -c 'apt-get update && apt-get install -y build-essential && apt-get install -y python'

COPY src /home/$user/
WORKDIR /home/$user

RUN npm install --production

CMD [ "npm", "start" ]
```

This is the package.json

```
{
    "name": "generic-cloud-node-sql",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
        "start": "node ./bin/www",          
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "@google-cloud/bigquery": "^4.0.0",
        "@google-cloud/storage": "^2.5.0",
        "body-parser": "*",
        "cron": "^1.7.1",
        "dateformat": "^3.0.2",
        "express": "*",
        "form-data": "*",
        "multer": "^1.4.1",
        "njwt": "*",
        "promise-mysql": "^3.3.1",
        "request": "^2.88.0",
        "request-ip": "^2.1.3",
        "throw.js": "*",
        "bcrypt": "^3.0.6",
        "winston": "*",
        "winston-gke": "*"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "chai": "^4.2.0",
        "mocha": "^5.2.0",
        "chai-http": "*"
    }
}
```

It fails when it tries to install `bcrypt` with the message

> ```
> Step #1: > bcrypt@3.0.6 install /home/node_modules/bcrypt
> Step #1: > node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build
> Step #1:
> Step #1: node-pre-gyp WARN Using request for node-pre-gyp https download
> Step #1: node-pre-gyp ERR! Completion callback never invoked!
> Step #1: node-pre-gyp ERR! System Linux 4.15.0-1044-gcp
> Step #1: node-pre-gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/home/node_modules/.bin/node-pre-gyp" "install" "--fallback-to-build"
> Step #1: node-pre-gyp ERR! cwd /home/node_modules/bcrypt
> Step #1: node-pre-gyp ERR! node -v v10.15.3
> Step #1: node-pre-gyp ERR! node-pre-gyp -v v0.12.0
> Step #1: node-pre-gyp ERR! This is a bug in `node-pre-gyp`.
> Step #1: node-pre-gyp ERR! Try to update node-pre-gyp and file an issue if it does not help:
> ```

**But the above Dockerfile and package.json works successfully when I run `docker build` locally.**

- No node_modules copied to the docker image
- No package_lock.json copied to the docker image
- The build process started to fail without any of the relevant files changed (Dockerfile, package.json etc)

What could be the issue?

Comment: Understood, my fault, I read too quickly your COPY line.

Comment: There is nothing wrong here. I would recommend you to give it a go again. bcrypt would typically fail if you don't have C/CXX compilers installed which you already installing in build-essential.

Comment: It fails in cloudbuild with the above message.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like more like an issue with node-pre-gyp than with Cloud Build. I found [this](https://github.com/mapbox/node-pre-gyp/issues/477) issue on GitHub that matches the issue that you are experiencing. It's definitely worth looking.